# wp_signon not loggin in user to WordPress

Tags: login, wp-login-form, wp-signup

I'm using the below script to log the user in, but when I run an `if` statement for `is_user_logged_in()`, but it doesn't seem to return the user as logged in.

```
<?php if( isset($_POST['username']) ){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $remember = $_POST['remember'];

    $user = get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    $user_id = $user->ID;

    if( $remember == 'on' ){
        $remember_pass = true;
    } else {
        $remember_pass = false;
    }

    if ( $user && wp_check_password( $password, $user->data->user_pass, $user->ID) ){
        $credentials = array(
            'user_login' => $username,
            'user_password' => $password,
            'remember' => true,
        );
        $auth = wp_signon( $credentials, false );
        if ( is_wp_error($auth) ){
            $auth->get_error_message();
        } else {
            echo '<p>Success.</p>';
        }
    } else {                    
        echo '<div class="result-box warning">Wrong username or password. Please try again.</div>';
    }
} ?>
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Everything is posting correctly, and the `array()` is working fine. If I run a `is_wp_error()` with the `$auth`, I still get a success message. So it's login in, just not actually giving them a session?

Comment: I've figured it out, I just need to add it before the `get_header()`, but why is this?

Comment: Logging in sets cookies, you can't set cookies after output has started.